# How to test that a mailable was sent from a notification?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-mail, laravel-notification

What's the secret of testing a mailable was sent from a notification?

Testing the notification:

```
it('does send notification when model is deleted', function() {
    Notification::fake();
    $this->model->delete();
    Notification::assertSentTo($this->model->user, MyModelDeletedNotification::class);
});
```

Passes.

Testing the mailable:

```
it('does send email when model is deleted', function() {
    Mail::fake();
    $this->model->delete();
    Mail::assertQueued(MyModelDeletedMail::class, 1);
});
```

Fails. No mails queued.

When a model is deleted a observer method is triggered:

```
public function deleted(MyModel $model)
{
    if ($model->isForceDeleting()) {
        return;
    }

    $model->user->notify(new MyModelDeletedNotification($model));
}
```

Notification:

```
class MyModelDeleted extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    ...

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail', 'database'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MyModelDeletedMail($this->model))->to($notifiable->email);
    }

    ...
}
```

Mailable:

```
class ConsultationDeleted extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    ...

    public function build()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I dump("foobar") inside the mailables constructor or build method, the message is appearing in the log. However the test fails. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer help you out? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/testing-if-email-was-sent-with-out-sending-it?page=1&replyId=402801

Comment: Since you're asserting the `Mail` is queued and not sent, are you also running `Queue::fake()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding using Mail:fake in the context of notifications:

> It is not a very good way to test because it catches only mails sent
> using the Mail facade (doesn't intercept mails sent through a
> notification or using a mailer retrieved via dependency injection).

Make sure you have set

```
<server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
```

phpunit.xml. In your test:

```
it('does send email', function() {

    // business logic

    $emails = app()->make('mailer')->getSwiftMailer()->getTransport()->messages();

    assertCount(1, $emails);
    assertEquals([$this->user->email], array_keys($emails[0]->getTo()));
});
```

This worked for me using laravel 8.

Reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/testing-if-email-was-sent-with-out-sending-it?page=1&replyId=402801